# unable to get count in mongodb collection.find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose ODM for a application. I am trying to count the number of items returned by a model like this:

```
 app.post("/verifyLogin",function(request,response){
var usr=request.body.username;
var pass=request.body.password;

response.send(userModel.find({$and:[{username:"admin"},{password:"admin"}]}).count());

});
```

But i get in return:

```
   {
  "options": {
    "populate": {}
  },
  "_conditions": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "username": "admin"
      },
      {
        "password": "admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  "_updateArg": {},
  "op": "count"
}
```

I expected a number :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `Model.count` method, in your case:

```
userModel.count({$and:[{username:"admin"},{password:"admin"}]}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
       //handle errors
    } else {
       response.send({count :result});
    }
});
```

Also: you're in node.js world - use callbacks.

The result you're getting now is the result of the `count` call on the `Model.find()` result (which, i think, is a query object), not the count of the query results.

Comment: i get a blank response the way you suggested :(

Comment: i get '1' when fired this on mongodb shell: db.users.find({$and:[{username:"admin"},{password:"admin"}]}).count()

Comment: @beNerd what do you get if you `console.log(result)` in the callback?

Comment: yes i get a one. but i wonder why its not sending it as a response.

Comment: @beNerd i forgot that res.send treats the first argument as response code if it's a number - updated the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26031/discussion-between-benerd-and-soulcheck)